# Add shifted integers to list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of integers, which I would like to inflate to include both the current integers, and their values shifted by +1 and -1.

For example, if I have :

```
l1 = [3, 9, 15]
```

I would like the result to be (the order doesn't matter) :

```
l2 = [2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16]
```

I can achieve it by doing this :

```
l1 = [3, 9, 15]
l2 = l1[:]
l2.extend([i-1 for i in l1])
l2.extend([i+1 for i in l1])
```

However, is there a **shorter / more efficient way** to do this (using `numpy` if appropriate) ?

*Please note that I would also like the "inflation" to work asymmetrically and with more than 2 added values, for example with -3, -2 and -1.*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it, except I would never use lists when order is not relevant. Set is the correct data type here.

Comment: @zvone, why would you use a set?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Because list is an ordered container. It is unclear here what the purpose of the data is, but if OP does not care about the order, it is a fair assumption that the container will later be searched in a manner which will make a set more suitable. I also have a feeling that duplicates are not welcome in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
l1 = [3, 9, 15]
l2 = [i+j for i in l1 for j in (-1, 0, 1)]

print (l2)
```

gives:

```
[2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use list comprehension with [`range()`](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) as:

```
>>> [item + i for item in l1 for i in range(-1, 2)]
[2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

With numpy is something like this

```
value=1
p = np.array([3, 9, 15])
p = np.append(p,[[[i+value,i-value] for i in p]])
```

with output sorted:

```
[2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16]
```

but you want with value 2 show for example in **3** [1,3,5] or [1,2,3,4,5] ?

if you want the second options is something like this

```
value=2
p = np.array([3, 9, 15])
p = np.append(p,[[[i+range(1,value+1),i-range(1,value+1)] for i in p]])
```

output sorted:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```